# Mudar src de imagem quando valor do input for igual a determinado valor

Tags: javascript, html, css

Boa noite!
Eu tenho um input de login e um img com a imagem do usuário.
Estou tentando alterar a imagem do usuário quando este input perder o foco e se o valor digitado corresponder a um valor determinado.
ex: se eu digitar nesse input Batata vou mudar o src apontando para minha imagem batata.png ao invés de no-user.png.

```
<img id="img" src="images/no-user.png" alt="Sem usuário">
<input name="Login" type="text" placeholder="Login" maxlength="20" onblur="carregarFoto(this.value)">
```

Alguém poderia me dar um exemplo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descobri a minha resposta. Criei essa função:

```
function carregarFoto(val) {
    document.getElementById("user").src="images/user.png";
}
```

e no `input` ficou assim:

```
<input name="Login" type="text" placeholder="Login" maxlength="20" onblur="carregarFoto(this.value)">
```